# Swift - Save checkmarks selected in TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, multi-select

I am fairly new to Swift and I am having an issue on TableView multi-selection. I have multiple selections that I can check with a checkmark, similar to to-do list.

When I check the items I want to be able to come back to the ListView and have my selections saved.
I'm assuming that the code to keep this in saved state would go somewhere here? This is the class where the individual cell item checkmark is written :

```
    class ListItem: NSObject {
    let itemName: String
    var completed: Bool

    init(itemName: String, completed: Bool = false)
    {
        self.itemName = itemName
        self.completed = completed
    }
}
```

Can Someone please show me how to go about this?

This is the cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let tempCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ListPrototypeCell") as UITableViewCell
    let listItem = listItems[indexPath.row]

    // Downcast from UILabel? to UILabel
    let cell = tempCell.textLabel as UILabel!
    cell.text = listItem.itemName

    if (listItem.completed)
    {
        tempCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark;
    }
    else
    {
        tempCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None;
    }

    return tempCell
}
```

and my didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)

    let tappedItem = listItems[indexPath.row] as ListItem
    tappedItem.completed = !tappedItem.completed

    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)

}
```

Comment: When you say "saved" what do you mean? Do you need your selections to persist between app opens? Will you be deallocating the view controller containing the table view and need to recreate its contents?

Comment: How are you storing the overall data? The completion state should be stored and then check when displaying the table as to whether it should be checked or not

Comment: Hi Lindsey, I mean I want to select the item and see my checkmark when I go back to the table view. As for deallocating the view controller and recreate its contents, I will only use the tableview for one particular portion of the app, thus no need for me to reuse any of its content. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, then as long as your view controller hasn't been deallocated, you won't lose any of that data so there's no need to save. And to answer your original question, the data should actually be accessible NOT in the custom cell, but in the same view controller as the tableview... If you're having any issues, my guess is that it either has to do with the code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or with the data structures (like the class array you should have to set your check booleans) in that same view controller.

Comment: @LyndseyScott What the flow is that I have a UIViewController with a button that calls the UITableView with a pop-Over. I can make the selection with the checkmarks but then they disappear when I click on the button again. Do I need to program core data functionality in order for the checkmarks to stay in its check mode?

Comment: @NatashaJulain Oh I see. No, you don't need to use core data unless you need that data to persist. Could you post your cellForRowAtIndexPath method so I could get an idea of your data structures? You should be able to just keep an array of the checkmarks boolean values within the UIViewController then populate the table with that array during cellForRowAtIndexPath. How are you setting the checks right now? In a separate method? If so, could you post that method too?

Comment: @LyndseyScott I have updated my question with my cellForRowAtIndexPath and didSelectRowAtIndexPath :)

Comment: @NatashaJulain Sorry needed some sleep, but I have an answer for you and I'm typing it out now.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

Your code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is perfect. It takes the info from `listItems[indexPath.row]` to populate your cell's text and checkmark. But in your  `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, you never change `listItems` such that `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` has the updated data from which to pull the new row upon reload.  So instead of using `deselectRowAtIndexPath:`, simply update the `listItems` array then `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`. (Honestly, I'm confused as to why it was working for you up to this point since you were calling reload on un-updated data.) Here's what I recommend:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let tappedItem = listItems[indexPath.row] as ListItem
    tappedItem.completed = !tappedItem.completed

    // Store the updated tappedItem back at the listItems index
    listItems[indexPath.row] = tappedItem

    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)

}
```

Secondly, as long as that array is being stored in a view controller that's not being deallocated, you won't lose that data and you'll be able to repopulate the table. But if it's being stored in a view controller (or table view controller) that's being deallocated, you may want to store it elsewhere in your program.

Comment: Good Morning :) I have updated my code with what you suggested. Cleaned the build, ran the code but it didn't do what I wanted. :( The items I selected still deselect.

Comment: @NatashaJulain I suspect it has something to do with the fact that the reload never was working for you in the first place... Like I said "I'm confused as to why it was working for you up to this point since you were calling reload on un-updated data." Your table was originally relying on `deselectRowAtIndexPath:` to make its changes. I'm going to think it over and get back to you in a bit... But just curious... What happens when you replace `tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(...` with  `tableView.reloadData()`? Does it work then?

Comment: I have solved it! I posted my Answer :) It was however using `NSUserDefaults` :/ You can take a look at what I did. Thank you for your valuable time to help.

Comment: @LyndseyScott Here in above example what is listItems. will you please explain it.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have an array of ListItem representing the model data (the contents of the table view). Then to preserve this *outside the running app* you can save it off into NSUserDefaults or into a file. To do so, you will need a way of serializing a ListItem. The usual way to do this is to have ListItem adopt the NSCoding protocol and implement `encodeWithCoder:` and `init(coder:)` to use NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver (the "coder" in those methods) to turn a ListItem object into an NSData and *vice versa*. Once you've done that, an array of ListItem can be directly serialized with NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver.

Comment: Here's an example for a simple Person object - not very different from your ListItem object: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch23p798basicFileOperations/ch36p1053basicFileOperations/Person.swift

Comment: Hi Matt, I am not sure how to call this in an array format. Is that how to adopt this? This is what I have for encodeWithCoder:

`required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    } `

Comment: @NatashaJulain You said you don't need to preserve the data outside the app (i.e. between app launches) so this is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this mixing and matching a bit, using NSUserDefaults
Here it goes:

Created a button in the navigation bar of my pop-over Table/ListView and functionalities to the button:

```
 //create a done button in the navigation bar
    var done = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Plain, target: self, action: Selector("doneBtn"))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = done

}

//This is the "Done" button functionality

func doneBtn()
{

    var saveString = ""

    for var i=0; i<listItems.count; i++
    {
        let listItem = listItems[i]
        if (listItem.completed)
        {
            saveString = saveString + "  " + "\(i)"
        }
    }

    saveString = saveString.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet .whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(saveString, forKey: "savedValues")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()


    self.navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)


    }
```

Then in my func for loading the initial data array, which holds my list items, created a variable savedValues which looked like this:

```
 var savedValues : String? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("savedValues") as? String



    if(!(savedValues==nil))
    {
        var nsStr: NSString = savedValues!
        let array = nsStr.componentsSeparatedByString("  ");
        for val in array {
            listItems[val.integerValue].completed = true
        }
    }
```

And naturally, don't forget to call `loadInitialData()` in your `viewDidLoad()`

Thank you to all that helped me out :)